# save values of array in one string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

i have an array with 4 values:

```
string[] selectedObject;
```

how can i save all 4 values of array in string like:

```
string selectedObjects = "";
```

i need one string like this:

```
selectedObjects = "123; 132; 231; 132;";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string selectedObjects = string.Join("; ", selectedObject);
```

This will produce the output `"123; 132; 231; 132"` - If you really wanted another `;` at the end you could add this manually to have all bases covered:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedObjects))
    selectedObjects = selectedObjects + ";";
```

This will produce the right output for any `selectedObject` array length, including zero.

Comment: What about the `;` at the end?

Answer (score -1):

```
String selectedObjects = selectedObject.Aggregate((aggregation, currentString) => aggregation + "; " + currentString);
```